# After refresh page results are change for dictsort() in django template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters, django-hvad

structure of model is i am using hvad for multilingual

```
class Course(TranslatableModel):

    translations = TranslatedFields(
        domain = models.ForeignKey('domain.Domain'),
        #track = models.ForeignKey('track.Track'),
        track = models.ForeignKey('track.Track', blank=True, null=True),
        course_nm = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name =_('Course Name')),
        nature_of_training = models.TextField(verbose_name = _('Nature of Training')),
        duration = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name =_('Duration')),
        sem = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name =_('Semester')),
        degree_level = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name =_('Degree Level')),
        credit = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name =_('Credits')),
        locations = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name =_('Locations')),
        accessible = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name =_('Accessible')),
        des = models.TextField(verbose_name = _('Description')),
        admission_details = models.TextField(verbose_name = _('Admission Details')),
        further_study_details = models.TextField(verbose_name = _('Further Study Details')),
        seats = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name =_('Seats')),
        title = models.CharField(max_length=512, verbose_name=_('Title')),
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=512, verbose_name=_('Slug')),
        created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True),
        updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True),
        created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, editable=False),



    )
```

pass object in context from view to template for sorting i apply this,

in views.py i simply pass objects in context

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

     context = super(DegreeDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

     context['courses'] = Course.objects.all()

return context
```

in template

```
                 {% for c in courses|dictsort:"track" %}

                    {% if c.domain|stringformat:"s" == d.domain_nm %}

                        {% if c.track != None %}
                            <h3>{{ c.track }}</h3>
                        {% endif %}

                      {{ c.course_nm }}

                    {% endif %}

                {% endfor %}
```

But After refresh page each time results are change,

so what i should do for sorting in django template,or any alternative is possible for sorting in django template
I try a lot but not find solution,

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Show the code of your view, that produce this template

Comment: @stalk in view simply pass object context['courses'] = Course.objects.all() return context

Answer (score 0):

I think, that the reason, why you get different results, is because `track` can be `null`:

```
track = models.ForeignKey('track.Track', blank=True, null=True),
```

So, courses with `track` field set to `null` will not have exact order, and therefore they will be rendered in random positions. So, either you need all `track` fields to be set to some value (and probably remove `blank=True, null=True` + apply migrations), either sort by another field.

Also, sorting models using `dictsort` in templates is not the best way to do. Better do it at database level, providing `order_by` to you queryset:

```
context['courses'] = Course.objects.all().order_by('track__id')
```

Comment: when i apply in view.py order_by('track_id') so it given following error "To access translated fields like 'track' from an untranslated model, you must use a translation aware manager, you can get one using nani.utils.get_translation_aware_manager"